# after create react app , npm start is not working , each time getting different errors

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npm-start

I tried `npm init`, update, cache clearing, `node js` uninstalled and
installed, but nothing helped

After create react app, `npm` start is not working, each time getting different errors:

```
D:\Downloads in Data drive\SourceCodes\Full Stack Web Development\NodeJs\Project A\client\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Downloads in Data drive\SourceCodes\Full Stack Web Development\NodeJs\Project A\client\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:5:16)   
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)





D:\Downloads in Data drive\SourceCodes\Full Stack Web Development\NodeJs\Project B\client copy\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7����%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Downloads in Data drive\SourceCodes\Full Stack Web Development\NodeJs\Project B\client copy\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:16:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

### My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ajv-dist": "^8.11.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Command Prompt` and locate the directory where you installed Node JS and run this command: `node --version`.
If it shows the version that you have installed, then run this command: `npm --version`. If it does not show the version then something is wrong.

Go to [Node JS Official Website](https://nodejs.org/en/) and download the Long Term Support(LTS) version of Node JS e.g 16.15.0 (according to the posting time of the answer).
Then install it and run the previous commands e.g. `node --version` & `npm --version`.

The error should be gone.